# Flutter OnTap Listview item

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter, may I know how to get different outputs when I click on each item? I have total of 3 lists, for each item, I want to get their respective output and now I only can get the same outputs for each item. How to get different outputs when I click on it? Thanks all.
[image]

this is my ListView coding :

```
class _CatState extends State<Cat> {
  List<String> categories = ["Furniture", "Lighting", "Decoration"];
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 25,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: categories.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildCategory(index),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget buildCategory(int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selectedIndex = index;
        });
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              categories[index],
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15,
                color: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.black : Colors.black45,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: DefaultPadding / 4), //top padding
              height: 2,
              width: 50,
              color: selectedIndex == index
                  ? Colors.blueAccent[200]
                  : Colors.transparent,
            )
          ],
```

When onTap the item:

```
class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;
  final Decor decoration;
  final Light light;
  final Function press;

  const ItemCard({
    Key key,
    this.press,
    this.product,
    this.decoration,
    this.light,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: press,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    // height: 180,
                    //  width: 160,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    product.img, // products image
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: DefaultPadding / 4),
                child: Text(
                  product.name, // products name
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                 product.price,
                 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              )
        ],
      ),
```

[image: Called function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use switch case if it is static. For example on itemBuilder in Gridview:

```
   ItemCard(
product:furniture[index],
press: _onPressed(index),
)
```

and in onPressed method, do whatever you want:

```
 _onPressed(int index){
switch(index):
case 0: 
your code:
break;
case 1:
//code
}
```

so by this you can make different onTap function